# Airflow Variable.set() violates unique key constraint

Tags: python, airflow

I'm currently running into an issue attempting to use Apache Airflow's Variable model as a key/value store to manage some state during an airflow job.

In one of the tasks in my job, I set a key to something like:

`Variable.set("{table_name}_last_run", "2020-04-16")`

later on, i try to overwrite this variable (for the same key) with a new value. When I do, airflow pukes and throws an error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1246, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 588, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "variable_key_key"
DETAIL:  Key (key)=(currency_last_run) already exists.
```

This doesn't make sense to me. According to airflow's documentation, it seems like you can use Variables like you would any other key/value store--yet it seems I can't overwrite a pre-existing key using the set() function.

Am I missing something or using Variables in an unintended way?

Comment: What version of Airflow are you using? This should work in Airflow 1.10.10

Comment: @kaxil 1.10.4 at the moment. was this a bug that was fixed potentially? Seems like a glaring issue if it is a bug so i'm erring on the side of "i've done something terribly wrong"

Comment: This should not occur in 1.10.4. Check the source code https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.4/airflow/models/variable.py#L122-L139 (Variable is deleted before new value is set)

Comment: Can you post your DAG or create a Dummy DAG that helps me reproduce the error

Comment: After doing more research, i think it may be happening because i'm constantly getting/setting this variable within a DAG itself. Inspecting some more examples, it seems like Variables aren't really intended to be used this way. Give me a bit and i can put together a dummy example.